# when creating an account i get the message: warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet

Tags: cleos, nodeos, accounts

I've built eos 1.4.3 and I'm using ubuntu 16.4

when creating an account I get this message

warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet

nodeos is runnig.

how come? it seems that it is not sending the account to the blockchain. 
[image]

Comment: it just tells you the transaction has been propagated but it can't tell you it was included in the blockchain. it most likely has been, but it can't know at that moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confused is correct.  I've been building since 1.07 and that's how it confirms.

Use `cleos get accounts [public key]` which should return the account name to confirm

API reference: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-accounts